# How to sum from 2 fields in XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, bi-publisher

Here's my XML

```
<ticket><sold>0</sold><price>7.00</price></ticket>
<ticket><sold>1</sold><price>7.00</price></ticket>
<ticket><sold>1</sold><price>7.00</price></ticket>
```

I want to sum the total sale prices, in this case it will be $14.00 because the 1st one does not sell any ticket

the  tag will only have 2 values (1 or 0)

The simplest way I think of is to multiple price with sold for each ticket and then sum it all up.

I group by  and below is my code but I got 0

```
0<?sum(current-group()/sold * current-group()/price)?>
```

Do you know why? If you have a simpler approach, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because from your try (`sum(current-group()/sold * current-group()/price)`) I assume you are looking for the sum of multiplication of sold and price. With xpath 2.0 you may try:

```
sum(//ticket[sold!=0]/(price * sold))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the value of `<sold>` is only ever 0 or 1 you can just do:

```
sum(//ticket[sold!=0]/price[.>0])
```

The last check (`[.>0]`) will ensure they are numeric nodes to make sure it will return correctly.

Comment: I don't think this will fit because the sum of sold multiply by sold seems to be wonted.